# PEPhotoCropEditor Archive Submission Errors

Tags: ios, frameworks, operating-system, plist, minimum

I am implementing the PEPhotoCropEditor in my app and when I submit the archive for a test build I get these errors. I have no clue how to fix any of these. Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Solved the issue. I was using cocoapods and so I went to the Pods-PEPhotoCropEditor and set the Deployment Target from 7.0 to 8.0. Everything is good now.